# Why is there a difference in Linear regression fitted values and predicted values on training data?

Tags: r

```
library(MASS)
data(Boston)
head(Boston)
index <- sample(nrow(Boston),nrow(Boston)*.80)
train <- Boston[index,]
test <- Boston[-index,]
model_1 <- lm(medv~.,data=train)
model_1train_p <- predict(model_1)
mean(model_1$fitted.values - model_1train_p)
```

Code to simulate the issue. I wanted to know why is there a non- zero difference.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The difference is because computers just can't handle decimal values **exactly**. The difference you get is very, very small, due to **internal** representation of any number (or any thing for that matters) as binary. It's just not always possibe to get an exact binary representation of a decimal.

If you want to check for equality of decimal numbers, use `all.equal`:

```
all.equal(model_1$fitted.values, model_1train_p)
```

Returns:

```
[1] TRUE
```